# Having a preset text sample (adjustable) in a form

Tags: angularjs

I'm unsure whether this is possible in Angular, which is why I'm posting my question here.

I am trying to setup a message to send in my application. When the page is loaded, the form should have a preset text such as

```
Hello {{ receiver }},

we have an appointment on {{ appointmentTime }}. This is moved to {{ newAppointmentTime }}.

Regards,

{{ sender }}
```

Is it possible to have a preset text set in a form WITH objects? The `receiver`, `appointmentTime`, `newAppointmentTime` and `sender` will be different depending on what time chosen and who is logged in which is why I would want to put the objects in the text form.

My current code looks like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea" rows="8" ng-model="object.email">
Hello {{ receiver }},

we have an appointment on {{ appointmentTime }}. This is moved to {{ newAppointmentTime }}.

Regards,

{{ sender }}</textarea>
```

but of course this doesn't work, because it's trying to load `object.email` which is empty, but I also want to fill it with the text above. This text also needs to be adjustable for the user (if the user would like to add some extra information to the message). I also realize a text form can have a placeholder, but this wouldn't work with a standard format (with spaces) and objects.

How would this be done in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initially compile your message in the controller and assign it to the variable that will hold your model - object.email. When you bind your text area to this, it will then populate your text area with your compiled message.

[Here is an example plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/dXU9yqa68ulTHbBLE2tx?p=preview), with an excerpt of the initialisation code below:

```
  function controller(){
      var vm = this;

      vm.receiver = "Dave";
      vm.time = "January 2nd 2016 at 17:00";
      vm.newAppointmentTime = "January 4th at 12:00";
      vm.sender = "Daisy";
      vm.messageText = "";

      function init(){
        vm.messageText = "Hello " + vm.receiver + ", \n\nWe have an appointment on " + 
        vm.time + ". This is moved to " + vm.newAppointmentTime + "." +
        "\n\nRegards,\n\n" + vm.sender;
      }


      init();

  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually does work. I didn't realize '\n' would be a breakline. After discussing with my project team, we figured out it's easier to do this in the back-end also due the fact that the entire preset text can be changed easier. But this is a very nice solution nonetheless. I will keep this in mind in case I happen to bump into a similar situation where it's not possible from the backend.

Comment: @Johnson nice idea - keeping your controllers thin!